# How can std::string operator[] return a reference rather than the character?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was going through the book Effective C++ by Scott Meyers and while reading Item 3 - Use `const` whenever possible found this example quite misleading.

My question is - How can an array access return a reference at the interested index rather than the item at that index.

Also attaching the program for reference here that I executed to confirm that this is happening

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TextBlock
{
    public:
        explicit TextBlock(const std::string str) : text(str) {}
        const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const { return text[position]; }
        char& operator[](std::size_t position) { return text[position]; }

        std::string get_text() { return text; }

    private:
        std::string text;
};

int main()
{
    TextBlock tb("Hello");
    cout << "Before calling operator overloading " << tb.get_text() << "\n";
    tb[0] = 'I';
    cout << "After calling operator overloading " << tb.get_text() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I got the corresponding output

```
Before calling operator overloading Hello
After calling operator overloading Iello
```

Is the observed behaviour something specific to operator overloading?

Comment: `std::string`'s overloaded operator `[]` returns a reference, you're just forwarding it from the overloaded `[]` of your class. So you get a reference as operator result, and can modify the string contents using this reference. What is your intention?

Comment: @AlexShesterov I wanted to know how accessing a string by the index value returns the reference to the location of interest and not the item in question. Your answer helped me. Is this such a basic doubt that needs a down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. I'll give you an upvote to compensate the `-1`.

Comment: The reason *why* an `operator[]` typically returns a reference is that an array index expression yields an lvalue. That is, let `int arr[10] = {};`, then the expression `arr[2]` is an lvalue: `arr[2] = 42;` is well-formed. The overloaded `operator[]` of `std::string` imitates the built-in array indexing in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is - How can an array access return a reference at the interested index rather than the item at that index.

It **isn't** an array access. You are calling the following overload of `std::string` when you do `text[position]`.

```
char& std::string::operator [] ( std::size_t index ) ;
```

which returns a *reference* to a character in the specified location of the string, which effectively is a container of chars. This is similar to how other containers work, such as `std::map` or `std::vector`. This behaviour is made possible by overloading the indexing operator for a class. It would otherwise be undefined since indexing is only possible on pointers/arrays or classes with the overload implemented.

With that said, it should be kept in mind that array indexing is effectively a pointer dereference, which means it can be bound to a reference in the same way and lead to the same results, like below (try it out). That is because `carray[i]` is equivalent to `*(carray + i)` which is one way to tell the compiler it is okay to implicitly cast your pointer to a reference.

```
char& operator [] ( std::size_t i ) { return carray[i]; }
...
char carray[10];
```

There are good reasons for the indexing operator to be implemented as such. It effectively allows you to treat `std::string` like you would a `char[]`; you can assign any given index a value as well as access any given index to get a value.